# Join two tables and compare two columns to see if they are equal

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

I have two tables in my access DB, I can join the tables based on their primary key, Grant Number, however both tables contain an expiry date column and I want to see if the expiry dates match.

```
First Table: "Everything2013" 
    Columns: Claim Name, Grant Number, Expiry Date

Second Table: "Yukon Claims Govt" 
    Columns: Claim Name, Claim Owner, Grant Number, StakingDate, ExpiryDate
```

I want to join the tables based on the Grant Number, which is the primary key, I then want to see if the expiry dates are the same for each grant number from both tables. Basically, I'm checking the expiry dates from one table to see if they match the expiry date for the same grant number in another table.

Comment: Grant Number is not included in the columns of `[Yukon Claims Govt]`, nor is `Expiry Date` for that matter?

Comment: Sorry, Grant Number is also a column in the Second Table, I missed that in my original message

Comment: Do you want to just be able to _see_ if the expiry dates match, or do you want to see only records with matching expiry dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select E.Claim_Name, E.Grant_Number, Y.StakingDate \
from Everything2013 e
inner join Yukon_Claims_Govt  y
on E.[Grant_Number]=Y.[Grant_number]
where E.Expiry_Date=Y.ClaimExpiryDate;
```

Comment: Now it does get more complicated if you need just dates and not datetimes and you are currently storing time values.

Comment: +1 but if Expiry date is nullable it may need a further condition `OR (e.[Expiry Date] IS NULL AND y.[Expiry Date] IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to get the result set which have same grant number and expiry date from two tables.

```
select Grant_Number,Claim_Name, StakingDate 
from Everything2013
inner join Yukon_Claims_Govt 
on Everything2013.Grant_Number=Yukon_Claims_Govt.Grant_Number
AND Everything2013.Expiry_Date=Yukon_Claims_Govt.ClaimExpiryDate;
```

Comment: This doesn't quite return the result I wanted, I think the WHERE is more useful for my situation.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Then why not You put join on expiry dates and extract the other fields.

Comment: I can't put the join on the expiry dates as they are not unique. Grant Numbers can have the same the expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
select Claim_Name, Grant_Number, StakingDate from Everything2013
inner join Yukon_Claims_Govt 
on Everything2013.Expiry_Date=Yukon_Claims_Govt.ClaimExpiryDate;
```